# Loop with SQL insert not removing spaces

Tags: sql, r, firebird, dbi

I have a situation where I created a loop to makes multiple inserts. However, white space is giving an error when making the SQL statement. Example below:

The code below works

```
query <- "INSERT INTO TBPPRODU (TBPCODIGO,PROCODIGO) VALUES (30084,'LD1268')"
dbSendQuery(con,query)
```

This does not work

```
prod <- data.frame(PROCODIGO=c("LD1268","LD1269","LD1270")

x <- data.frame(PROCODIGO=NA)

for (i in 1:nrow(prod)) {
  x[i,] <- prod[i,]
  query <- paste("INSERT INTO TBPPRODU (TBPCODIGO,PROCODIGO) VALUES (30084,'",x[i,"PROCODIGO"],"')",collapse = "")
  dbSendQuery(con,query)
}

## the error output says there is white space before ' LD1268'
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1655: 23000: [ODBC Firebird Driver][Firebird]violation of FOREIGN KEY constraint "PRODU_TBPPRODU" on table "TBPPRODU"
Foreign key reference target does not exist
Problematic key value is ("PROCODIGO" = ' LD1268')
```

I have tried to trim but is not working as well

```
query <- paste("INSERT INTO TBPPRODU (TBPCODIGO,PROCODIGO) VALUES (30084,'",x[trimws(i),"PROCODIGO"],"')",collapse = "")
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a reason you are brute-forcing data in the hard way, ignoring a function like `dbWriteTable` that does it more directly and faster?

Comment: Hi evans. Do you mean this function will replace the loop ?

Comment: Have you read anything from https://dbi.r-dbi.org/?

Comment: Not this source specifically, but I know some of this stuff. But nevertheless first  I need to find out why my loop is not getting it right. Then I can check other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things wrong with this approach.

1. Using `dbSendQuery(con, "INSERT INTO ...")` to insert data one row at a time. Create the `data.frame` first, then `dbWriteTable` it:

   ```r
   prod <- data.frame(PROCODIGO=c("LD1268","LD1269","LD1270"), TBPCODIGO=30084L)
   dbAppendTable(con, "TBPPRODU", prod)
   ```
2. I think there should be more care crafting *data* into queries. [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) can be both malicious (e.g., XKCD's [*Exploits of a Mom*](https://xkcd.com/327/) aka "Little Bobby Tables") as well as completely accidental. One should *never* `paste` "data" into a query string. Options:

   - Parameterized queries, see https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#parameterized-queries
   - `glue::glue_sql`, which is better than `paste` since it takes steps to ensure the data is escaped properly.
3. Even if you want to use `paste`, realize that it is adding spaces with the default `sep=" "` argument.

   ```r
   paste("VALUES (30084,'", "hello", "')")
   # [1] "VALUES (30084,' hello ')"                   # not right
   paste0("VALUES (30084,'", "hello", "')")
   # [1] "VALUES (30084,'hello')"
   paste("VALUES (30084,'", "hello", "')", sep = "")  # equivalent to paste0
   # [1] "VALUES (30084,'hello')"
   ```

Comment: I have changed collapse = "" for sep = "" and it worked. I will look into your advice to use dbAppendTable . Sounds simples and safer. Thanks you evans.